# Seekbar in android not scrolling on touch

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Code Run with no errors. But seekbar not working. It is the center but not able to slide on touch.

```
timesTablesSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                int min =1;
                int timesTableNumber;

                if(i<1){
                    timesTableNumber = min;
                }else{
                    timesTableNumber = i;
                }
                Log.i("Seekbar Value", Integer.toString(timesTableNumber));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: post your xml that contain seekbar

Comment: Post your **XML** code, I think a view overlay your `SeekBar`